# android - Youtube api 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

The YouTube Api is giving the following error, though I have provided "snippet" as part in the query and it is working well in debug version and not working in my signed Apk version

```
{
   "errors" : [ {
   "domain" : "global",
   "reason" : "required",
   "message" : "Required parameter: part",
   "locationType" : "parameter",
   "location" : "part"
   } ],
   "code" : 400,
   "message" : "Required parameter: part"
}
```

Here is my query code:
     query = youTube.playlists().list("snippet");

```
 query.setKey(getYTkey());
 query.setChannelId(con[0].getString(R.string.CHANNEL_ID));
 query.setMaxResults((long) 25);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the proguard rules as follows:

```
-keep class com.google.**
-keep interface com.google.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.google.**

-keep class com.google.api.** {
    *;
}

# Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**

# Needed by google-play-services when linking against an older platform version
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.**
# com.google.client.util.IOUtils references java.nio.file.Files when on Java 7+
-dontnote java.nio.file.Files, java.nio.file.Path

# Suppress notes on LicensingServices
-dontnote **.ILicensingService

# Suppress warnings on sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
```

Comment: great (y). Thanks a lot :)